# Should Baruch Hu Uvaruch Shemo ONLY be recited during blessings?

Tags: minhag, blessing

If one hears their friend reciting Torah verses, and says Hashem's name, should one recite BHUVS? Does this response only apply to brachot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ashkenazim only say it for (certain) blessings (see [Orach Chayim 124:5](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%9B%D7%93_%D7%94) and the [issue](http://www.daat.ac.il/encyclopedia/value.asp?id1=331) of Megillah reading and the blessings of the Shema). In addition, Sefardi Jews typically say *barukh hu uvarukh shemo* when the Divine Name is mentioned during the priestly blessing (see related questions [here](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/107481) and [here](http://www.chabad.org.il/Magazines/Article.asp?ArticleID=2747&CategoryID=817)), but during a regular Torah reading they don't say it either.

Comment: Many _Ashk'nazim_ say it in the priests' blessing, too.

Comment: I suppose because they heard it from Sefardim, but they shouldn't do so: האשכנזים נוהגים לא לענות  "ברוך הוא וברוך שמו" בברכת כהנים.

Comment: (re your comment) More likely IMO, they do it for the same reasons the _S'faradim_ do it.